# Access each instance of reactive form inside ngfor in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been going back and forth with this for a few hours as most answers I researched include thing's I don't want such as adding fields dynamically. All I want is to be able to access the property of each instance of the form. As of now it only prints one instance.

Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzzzql

html

```
<section class="exercises">
  <form
    fxLayout="column"
    fxLayoutGap="2px"
    [formGroup]="exerciseForm"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(exerciseForm.value)"
  >

    <ul *ngFor="let exercise of exercises">
      <li>{{ exercise.instruction }}</li>
      <ul *ngFor="let question of exercise.questions; let i = index">
        <li>
         {{ question.prefix }}
          <mat-form-field>
            <input
              name="answer"
              type="text"
              id="answer"
              matInput
              formControlName="answer">
          </mat-form-field>

          {{ question.sufix }} -
          {{ question.translation }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

ts

```
exercises: Exercise[]=[
    new Exercise (
      'Answer this question',
      [new Question (1,'Eu','maluco','I am crazy'),
       new Question (2,'Eu','doidinho','I am cuckoo')],
    )]

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

exerciseForm = this.fb.group({
    answer:['']
  })
ngOnInit(): void {

  }

onSubmit(answer: Answer) {
  console.log(this.exerciseForm.value)
}
}
```

Comment: You mean like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewpsyq

Comment: Exactly. Could you please explain the thought process? I'm looping through the property of the property (question of exercises) and adding a control to each instance, then binding each question to each control with [formControlName] using one of the questions properties?

Comment: I have added as an answer with step by step explanation of the solution.. Please feel free to accept if it resolves your issue..

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same `formcontrolName`, then you will receive only the last control value..

So how can we tweak your code??

In `app.component.ts`

Change:

```
exerciseForm = this.fb.group({
    answer:['']
  })
```

To:

```
exerciseForm:FormGroup;
```

Just initialize the `formgroup` here and don't assign any value for now..

You need to add a new function to create `formGroup` and call it inside `ngOnInit` life cycle hook.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createGroup()
}
```

Here to the earlier assigned `this.exerciseForm` , you need to assign the group value `this.fb.group({});`.

Then you need to form controls for the questions which is an array and you need to iterate in `ts` like,

`this.exercises[0].questions.forEach(control => ... )`

So inside this loop, you need to assign `control` to each item respectively, As `id` is the unique value, you can give it as control like,

```
this.exerciseForm.addControl(control.id, this.fb.control(''))
```

And the function as follows,

```
  createGroup(){
    this.exerciseForm = this.fb.group({});
    this.exercises[0].questions.forEach(control => 
      this.exerciseForm.addControl(control.id, this.fb.control(''))
    );
    return this.exerciseForm;
  }
```

And in `app.component.html`, just one change (Assigning unique `formcontrolname`)

Change,

```
formControlName="answer"
```

To

```
[formControlName]="question.id"
```

> [**Forked Stackblitz Here..**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewpsyq)

Answer (score 0):

Just make **formControlName** depended on **index** and then get it by name from **exerciseForm**

```
[formControlName]="'answer_' + question.id"
```

Get control:

```
this.exerciseForm.controls['answer_1']
```

OR

```
this.exerciseForm.get('answer_1')
```